# What is device ID value used in the write asset property file in tutorial-rest repo of tandem api?

Tags: javascript, autodesk-tandem

I am begineer and new to tandem.

I am trying to understand the git repo of tandem api/tutorial-rest in which while reading file write-asset-properties.js, I came accross variable called asset-property-id who value must be set by us and the default value given by the author is device id. I have know idea from where we need to get this value.

[This screenshot of the variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZV8u1.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [this specific example](https://github.com/autodesk-tandem/tutorial-rest/blob/main/assets/write-asset-properties.js) it refers to parameter name which is part of element classification. It can be anything what helps to identify asset in the facility - i.e. serial number or any other unique identifier.

You can use **Manage** tab to define your own classification and define necessary parameters.

[image]

Comment: Does this parameter value that your saying will only be available if I define a classification system or will their default value present for it? I'm unable find any parameter value for the sample(snowden towers sample facility) given by the autodesk.

Comment: Yep, you need to define it as part of your classification.